# Laravel 4 and Symlinks

Tags: php, laravel, symlink

So I'm new to Laravel 4, and I'm trying to figure out how to Symlink two parts of my site.

The first is **apps/storage**
The second is **public/cache** (this is where an image cache is stored)

I'd like to move both of these to a SSD on my server, however Laravel keeps throwing out an error whenever I try and setup these Symlinks.

That error is:

```
ErrorException
file_put_contents(/meta/services.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Clearly it's unable to find the filesystem and the symlink isn't working with Laravel. But the symlink DOES work with individual files (such as a jpeg), so I'm positive there is no problem with the initial setup.

To clarify, the document root is set to **httpdocs/public** (via Plesk settings)

The apps (and framework) are located in the  **httpdocs** folder which is no longer serving as the vhost root.

As I hinted at, it's a Plesk server. The owner belongs to the vhost, and the group belongs to psacln. But I don't think there are any permission/ownership problems, as I've verified the symlinks are working.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this has absolutely nothing to do with Laravel. `file_put_contents` is a native PHP function. Your problem almost certainly lies with permissions. Is it a shared host? In which case the '/meta' path will actually be something like '/path/to/user/meta'

Comment: Permissions all check out fine. And it's a dedi.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have messed something else, because the path in the error message looks wrong to me:

```
file_put_contents(/meta/services.json)
```

IMO, it should be something like:

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/webapp/app/storage/meta/services.json)
```

Because, if you have done the symlink correctly you did something like

```
mv /var/www/webapp/app/storage /mnt/ssd/
ln -s /mnt/ssd/storage /var/www/webapp/app/storage
```

PHP is trying to write a file in the root /meta folder, where probably it doesn't have right.